# Counting certain values in rows in SAS table

Tags: sas

I'm trying to count certain values in rows and require little help!

I have table that looks like this:

```
data test;
input a b c d;
cards;
1 0 9 1
1 1 0 0
0 9 1 1
0 0 9 1
1 0 9 9
0 1 1 0
1 9 9 1
1 9 0 0
0 0 9 1
9 1 0 0;
run;
```

Variables a,b,c and d can have values 1, 0 or 9. Now I need to to make a new variable that has value of 1 when there is two or more values of 9 in a row. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs clarifying... do mean two 9's anywhere in a single row, or two 9's in a row (i.e. consecutively)?

A simple way is to concatenate (using `cats()`) all the values into a string, and use the `index()` function to check for the '99', or `count()` to count the 9's...

```
data want ;
  set have ;

  array all{*} a b c d ;

  vallist = cats(of all{*}) ;
  has99 = (index(vallist,'99') > 0) ; /* flag any two consecutive 9's */
  two9s = (count(vallist,'9') >= 2) ; /* two or more 9's */

  drop vallist ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thank you! I ment two 9's anywhere and this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it.  Sum your rows and store it in a new variable, e, then if that sum is 18 or larger then you know there has to be at least 2 9's.

```
data test;
set test;
e = a+b+c+d;
IF e >= 18 THEN f = 1;
ELSE f = 0; 
DROP e;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data want;
   set test;
   flag=sum(of _all_)>=18;
run;
```